# Link restrictions for new users -- can we exclude 'localhost'?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

In a recent question I was answering, I had used localhost and your.domain.tld as examples for a user with regards to RWW and OWA.  However, I had to obfuscate the URL (think I put brackets around the colon) as I had exceeded the number of links permitted for my current rank.

Could we modify the parser to have a "whitelist" of URLs like 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' and possibly anything ending in .local?

Comment: As they're not real links I think they should be excluded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe `example.com`, (and `example.net`, `example.local`, etc) since that's the domain that's actually [reserved for this purpose](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606).

Comment: maybe the .local TLD as well...

Comment: Is it really reserved?  By whom?  IEEE? Or do you mean just at SF/SO.  Curious...

Comment: Wow, I just went to example.com and have never seen that before.  That's great.  I thought for sure some squatters owned that.

Comment: Yep, there's actually [an RFC about this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606).

Answer (score 6):

Try formatting them as code using backticks, e.g. `http://localhost`.

In addition to not counting against the link limit, it also prevents them from rendering as links in the first place, which is nice (they wouldn't link to anywhere useful anyway).

Comment: I disagree that they aren't useful. When a user is developing locally, and using a development server, being able to provide them with a link that actually goes to their page is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with this. There are lots of times where we want the person to be able to click on a link to localhost, where she is running a dev server on her machine.

For instance, I just attempted to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113378/using-python-default-development-http-server-error-the-current-url-didnt-m/11113416#11113416), and could not enter a link to localhost for this user to use: instead it needs to be marked as code.