# Is there any chance the localhost link restriction will be lifted?

Tags: feature-request, link-validator

Is there any chance that localhost links will be allowed again, or is that a completely closed subject? I've seen these posts, but neither seems to have a clear answer:

[The link validator is overzealous and should allow posting so-called 'invalid' links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134229/the-link-validator-is-overzealous-and-should-allow-posting-so-called-invalid-l)

[Link restrictions for new users -- can we exclude 'localhost'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/link-restrictions-for-new-users-can-we-exclude-localhost)

Sometimes I answer questions by providing code on Github with instructions on how to clone and run it, and sometimes that means starting a local server. In those cases, it's really nice to be able to provide a localhost link as the final step in the process. Perhaps they could be re-allowed based on reputation if it's mainly a "new user" error?

Here are a couple of examples from before localhost was disallowed:

[Cannot Autowire Service into Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692855/cannot-autowire-service-into-controller/7699922#7699922)

[Configuring Integration Tests using Spring/Jetty (or Tomcat)/Maven for REST tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538564/configuring-integration-tests-using-spring-jetty-or-tomcat-maven-for-rest-test/7462344#7462344)

Comment: I don't know why, but links like this make me very uncomfortable. They aren't *supposed* to be universally meaningful at all. That'd be like someone linking `http://192.168.1.1` because it's a common address for a NAT router. I understand your use case, but I'm not sure if it's a big enough issue.

Comment: @Andrew: I understand that reasoning to a point, but these *are* universal links that work for everybody every time, unlike http://192.168.1.1, which might instead be http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.254. I guess it's the "if it's a big enough issue" that I'm really trying to find out about. It's definitely an issue. It's just a matter of whether it has enough traction with the right people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localhost in URL = numeric?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167525/localhost-in-url-numeric)

Comment: @ChrisF: This is *not* a dupe of that question. This one is a feature request to lift the restriction, the other is a bug report on the spelling of the error message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I wan't sure either, which is why I left it as a question.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify *localhost* in the code block instead of making it as an actual link. OP should be able to copy and paste the localhost from the code block.

```
http://localhost:8080/TestURL
```

See the answer from [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) to the following question.

[Localhost in URL = numeric?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167525/localhost-in-url-numeric)

Comment: I understand that a non-link via code block is possible, but that's not what I'm asking. I want localhost links back because they *are* useful, and a "click" is much more convenient than a "click and drag to select the url, right click, copy, click and drag in the address bar, delete, right click, paste". I'm not saying this is the best or fastest way to follow a non-link link, but it's the way that I see most people do it, and since that's the case, this is kind of a big deal as far as usability goes.

Comment: @RyanStewart: Sorry, I have no idea about that. Based on that reply from Marc Gravell, I assume that implementing localhost might not be preferred but I could be totally wrong.